# New GMail API Signatures Settings

Tags: gmail-api, google-email-settings-api

I've tested the EMail Settings API with many third party tools, and it seems to strip inlined embedded images (Base64), however the WebGUI can create inline embedded images in signatures with some browsers.

Has this been improved in GMAIL API Signatures? Will the new API accept (or continue to strip) inlined embedded images?

Comment: Are you talking about [Email Settings API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_signature_settings), you may check the document regarding on how to manage signature [settings](https://support.google.com/a/answer/175190?hl=en).

Comment: No I'm talking about the new Gmail API changes just released. The documentation does not answer this question. It states "Google will sanitise the signature" with no indication of what html is and is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail does not support inline image embedding for signatures, only image linking.

In general, the API doesn't provide any capabilities beyond what the UI already provides.

Comment: Ahh this is incorrect. You can inline embed an image by copying and pasting an already inline embedded image from Outlook for example into Chrome in the GMail signatures box. We have an entire company set up with inline embedded images, we'd just like to be able to do it with the API rather than each user manually.